# Query user id by limit based on distance using georadius

Tags: java, redis, apache-flink, geospatial, lettuce

StackOverflow community,

I am working on a Flink java application to query distance between users. I am using the lettuce framework to query userID given

```
GEORADIUS <location> <lat> <lon> <radius> <unit>.
```

Condition -> Now imagine there are millions of userID within given parameters.

Question -> What would be the best way to query the user ids using the lettuce framework while not querying a million users in a single query?

I know sorted sets have `limit` via which we can seamlessly keep track of the last offset and continue querying from that point.  However, geo API provides `count` which provides only top n userID. Is there something similar we can do using georadius command?

Or is there a better way to solve the problem, where we can query userID without repeating results within given radius bounds?
I know we can reduce distance but, is there a way to gat delta between r1 and r2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `GEORADIUS` command with `STORE` or `STOREDIST` options to save the result into a sorted set. Then you can use the `ZRANGE` command to iterate the result.

Comment: Thanks, sounds like a fair approach. I totally skipped the store and store dist part in the documentation.